# Symfony one to one Bidirectional embedded forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony2-forms

I have one-to-one bidirectional relationship between user and
institute. Each user can own an institute at a time and each institute
is owned by one user at a time. What i wanted to do is i have
institutes data in my institute table, now i want to create user and
during creating user, i want to assign him an institute.

I am using embedded form as collection, but the issue is the data is not loaded in embedded form.

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="PNC\InstitutesBundle\Entity\Institutes", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     */
    protected $institute;
}


class Institutes {
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="institute")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

The UserInstituteType form.

```
 $builder->add('name', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
        //'mapped' => false,
        'required' => false,
        'class'=>'PNC\InstitutesBundle\Entity\Institutes',
        'property'=>'name',
        'multiple' => false,
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control'
        )
        ));
```

and in Usertype form.

```
 ->add('firstname','text',array(
                'label' => ucfirst('First Name *'),
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => $constraints['firstname'],
                'attr'=> array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'autocomplete' => 'off'
                ),
                'label_attr'=> array(
                    'class' => 'control-label',
                ),
                ))
            ->add('lastname','text',array(
                'label' => ucfirst('Last Name *'),
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => $constraints['lastname'],
                'attr'=> array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'autocomplete' => 'off'
                )))
            ->add('username', 'text', array(
                'required' => true,
                'pattern' => '^\(\d{5}\)-\d{7}-\d{1}$',
                'label' => ucfirst('NIC *'),
                'max_length' => 15,
                'constraints' => $constraints['username'],
                'attr'=> array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'autocomplete' => 'off'
                )
            ))
      ->add('institute',new UserInstituteType(),array(
                    'data_class' => 'PNC\InstitutesBundle\Entity\Institutes',
                    'label' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                ))
```

and in controller

```
public function newAction(Request $request){
   $user = new User();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $institutes = new Institutes();
        $user->setInstitute($institutes);
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('pnc_users_users_new'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));
}
```

The issue is the form is rendering well, but in institute drop down,
no data is loaded so that i can pick an institute and assign it to
user. New/little exp in symfony, so stuck in this, don't know where is have done wrong...

Comment: If you replace your `UserInstituteType` by a simple `entity`. Did it show a select with data?

Comment: Yes, I am doing this as before..

Comment: it saves the user, but in institute table the user_id column is still empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use the type `entity` for the `institute` field in the form type. When all is working, you can test again the genemu form type.

Next, I think that you have an issue with yours setter. Because of your comment:

> it saves the user, but in institute table the user_id column is still empty.

```
class User extends BaseUser
    {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="PNC\InstitutesBundle\Entity\Institutes", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     */
    protected $institute;

    public function setInstitute(Institute $institute)
    {
        // Set the owning side of the relation!
        $institute->setUser($this);
        $this->institute = $institute;
    }
}


class Institutes {
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="institute")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

You need to set the owning side of the relation, if you don't no data will be saved.

Comment: Thanks, I have spend my whole day to get rid of this manually, putting it into db manually from queries.... your answer just did it. awesome.

Comment: Can you suggest me a solution for this one too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868697/symfony-assign-multiple-values-at-once-in-bridge-entity-form