# Symfony Assign multiple values at once in Bridge Entity Form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, jquery-select2

I have below relationship between my entities.

One to many between `Institute` -> `InstituteCourses`. One to many between `Courses` -> `InstituteCourses`.

I have avoid making many to many between instiutes and courses because i have alot more fields in instiutecourses entity.

For now it is working well,

```
    class Institutes {
        /**
        * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InstitutesCourses", mappedBy="institute", cascade={"all"})
        **/
        protected $instituteCourses;
    }
    class Courses {
        /**
         *
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InstitutesCourses", mappedBy="course", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
         */
        protected $instituteCourses;
    }

    class InstitutesCourses {
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Institutes", inversedBy="instituteCourses")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="institute_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $institute;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Courses", inversedBy="instituteCourses")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $course;
  /**
     * @var boolean $isPrimary
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_primary", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $isPrimary;
   /**
     * @var boolean $verified
     * @ORM\Column(name="courses_verified", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $verified;
    /**
     * @var boolean $active
     * @ORM\Column(name="courses_active", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $active;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AcademicSessions", mappedBy="instituteCourse")
     */
    protected $academicSession;
    }
```

and the form is

```
 $builder->add('institute','entity', array(
                    'class'=>'PNC\InstitutesBundle\Entity\Institutes',
                    'property'=>'name',
                    'label' => 'Institute'
                )
            )
            ->add('course', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PNC\CoursesBundle\Entity\Courses',
                'property' => 'courseTitle',
                //'multiple' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                )
            ))
```

Now if i want to assign one institute mulitple courses i have to all new Action several time, what i wanted to in single submit multiple courses allocated to one institute. when i set multiple = true in courses field in form. it gives error.

UPDATE -

```
class Institutes {

  /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NC\InstitutesBundle\Entity\InstitutesCourses", mappedBy="institute", cascade={"all"})
     * */
    protected $inst;
    protected $courses;


 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->inst = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->courses = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Important
    public function getCourses()
    {
        $courses = new ArrayCollection();

        foreach($this->inst as $ins)
        {
            $courses[] = $ins->getCourses();
        }
        return $courses;
    }

    // Important
    public function setCourses($courses)
    {


        foreach($courses as $c)
        {
            $po = new InstitutesCourses();
            $po->setCourse($c);
            $po->setInstitute($this);
            $this->addInst($po);
        }

    }

    // Important
    public function getCourse()
    {
        return $this;
    }
    // Important
    public function addInst($InstitutesCourses)
    {
        $this->inst[] = $InstitutesCourses;
    }
    // Important
    public function removeIns($InstitutesCourses)
    {
        return $this->inst->removeElement($InstitutesCourses);
    }
```

}
And

```
class Courses {
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NC\InstitutesBundle\Entity\InstitutesCourses", mappedBy="course", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $instituteCourses;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getInstituteCourses()
    {
        return $this->instituteCourses;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $instituteCourses
     */
    public function setInstituteCourses($instituteCourses)
    {
        $this->instituteCourses = $instituteCourses;
    }
}
```

and the bridge entity.

```
class InstitutesCourses {

/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PNC\InstitutesBundle\Entity\Institutes", inversedBy="instituteCourses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="institute_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $institute;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PNC\CoursesBundle\Entity\Courses", inversedBy="instituteCourses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $course;
 /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getInstitute()
    {
        return $this->institute;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $institute
     */
    public function setInstitute($institute)
    {
        $this->institute = $institute;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCourse()
    {
        return $this->course;
    }
    /**
     * @param mixed $course
     */
    public function setCourse( $course)
    {
        $this->course = $course;
    }

}
```

I made a form of institute type,

```
->add('courses' , 'entity' , array(
'class'    => 'PNCCoursesBundle:Courses' ,
'property' => 'courseTitle' ,
//'expanded' => true ,
'multiple' => true ,
'attr'=> array(
      'class' => 'form-control',
),
'label_attr' => array(
'class' => 'control-label'
),
)
```

Now When i Go to Create a New It perfectly saves the record, when I update the same record it says.

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getCourses" of class
>   "NC\InstitutesBundle\Entity\InstitutesCourses". Did you mean to call
>   e.g. "getCourse" or "setCourse"?

Comment: Can you please add an example of the fields in `InstitutesCourses`. That would change the meaning of the relation. If the field are relative to one course and one institude or no.

Comment: @Kevinrob check the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You try mix two different approach.
First:  to make many to many relation between institutes and courses. Create form for institutes Entity, where courses is collection. In that approach doctrine create records in InstitutesCourses table for each course byself.
Second: You create form for InstitutesCourses Entity. One form - one entity. In this case you must use one of the work around solution. One of them:
1. In Form Type make 'courses' as not mapped field ('mapped'=false)
2. After submitting form get array of 'courses' in Controller

```
$courses=$form->get('courses')->getData();
```

3. Make loop for each course in courses with creating InstitutesCourses manually like that:

   foreach ($courses as $course) {
      $institutesCourse=new InstitutesCourses();
      $institutesCourse->setCourse($course)
          ->setInstitutes($institute);
      $em->$persist($institutesCourse);
   }
   $em->flush();